# Javascript Prototype Chaining - Multiple Objects, Commom Prototype

Tags: javascript

As described in Javascript, methods and properties are not copied over form one object to other in prototype chain, My question is how same properties in different objects with different value is maintained ? Please look the code below to get clear idea about my question.

```
function Person( name ){ 
   this.name = name;
   this.greeting = function() {
      alert( 'Hi I\'m ' + this.name + '.' );
   }
}
var p1 = new Person( 'Mr. X' );
var p2 = new Person( 'Mr. Y' );

p1.greeting();
p2.greeting();
```

Here we have created two objects person1 and person2. As Prototype Object's properties and methods will be linked and will not be copied over to p1 and p2 how these objects are going to maintain their name property ( 'Mr.X and Mr.Y') separately, and show respective names in greeting message ?

Comment: its not linked to prototype

Comment: This is from MDN documentation of javascript - "In classic OOP, classes are defined, then when object instances are created all the properties and methods defined on the class are copied over to the instance. In JavaScript, they are not copied over — instead, a link is made between the object instance and its prototype "

Comment: in your case the function and property are not in the prototype chain.so it will be in every object as aproperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your `name` and also `greeting` properties are not in the prototype, but each object has it's own properties with name `name` and `greeting`.

If you want to add something that will be shared across all instances you need to assign it in the `Person.prototype` object. Here property with name `greeting` is shared across all instances.

```js
function Person( name ){ 
   this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
   alert( 'Hi I\'m ' + this.name + '.' );
}

var p1 = new Person( 'Mr. X' );
var p2 = new Person( 'Mr. Y' );

p1.greeting();
p2.greeting();
```

The difference about `greeting` in the `prototype` or in the instance you can look here. When I change the `greeting` property for one object, it will affect only that one.

```js
function Person( name ){ 
   this.name = name;
   this.greeting = function() {
      alert( 'Hi I\'m ' + this.name + '.' );
   }
}

var p1 = new Person( 'Mr. X' );
var p2 = new Person( 'Mr. Y' );

p1.greeting = function() {};
p1.greeting();
p2.greeting();
```